# Socket.io doesn't fire disconnect on browser back button in my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I ran into an issue with react where pressing the browser "back" button on my inner page (thus going back to my outer page) doesn't fire the socket disconnect event. Refreshing, closing the browser, etc fire the disconnect event just fine.

I'm using react-router-dom like so:

```
const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" exact component={OuterComponent} />
    <Route path="/innercomponent" component={InnerComponent} />
  </Router>
);
```

I tried to fix this issue by firing socket disconnect on browser back in my InnerComponent:

```
useEffect(() => {window.onpopstate = e => {
      socket.emit("disconnect");
      socket.off();
      console.log("socket disconnect should fire.");
    };
}
```

But the disconnect event doesn't fire despite the console.log triggering when I click the back button. I'm assuming this issue is related to the react router.

Comment: Looks like I was using a deprecated socket method. the answer from @i.brod solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are running this effect after each render(thus shutting down the socket, if i understand correctly what's going on), You need to run it only when the component unmounts:

```
useEffect(()=>{    
    return ()=>{
      socket.close();
    }
  },[])
```

I don't see a "socket.off()" method, maybe you're using an old version of SocketIO? In the latest version at least, socket.close() is used to shutdown the connection manually. Anyway, i tested it and it seems that this is how your useEffect should be set up.

Comment: Using socket.close() instead of socket.off() totally fixed the issue. I was actually already passing an array to useEffect so the only issue was fail to disconnect on browser back.

Comment: Where did you see socket.off()? I wasn't even aware something like that existed. Was it like that in some old version, or is it just a mistake on your part? Anyway, i would strongly recommend to make the docs of SocketIO your friend, they are pretty good

Comment: i saw it in an old socketio project, obviously it's deprecated lol